# Bot Framework Node.js translation with Bing Translate API according to prefered language

Tags: javascript, node.js, locale, botframework, translate

I am trying to implement translation feature within bot developed with Node.js Bot Builder SDK. I found [sample](https://github.com/alyssaong1/BotTranslator) where this translation is done like this:

```
bot.use({
    receive: function (event, next) {
            var token = tokenHandler.token();
            if (token && token !== ""){ //not null or empty string
                var urlencodedtext = urlencode(event.text); // convert foreign characters to utf8
                var options = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate'+'?text=' + urlencodedtext + '&from=' + FROMLOCALE +'&to=' + TOLOCALE,
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                    }
                };
                request(options, function (error, response, body){
                    //Check for error
                    if(error){
                        return console.log('Error:', error);
                    } else if(response.statusCode !== 200){
                        return console.log('Invalid Status Code Returned:', response.statusCode);
                    } else {
                        // Returns in xml format, no json option :(
                        parseString(body, function (err, result) {
                            console.log(result.string._);
                            event.text = result.string._;
                            next();
                        });
                        
                    }
                });
                } else {
                    console.log("No token");
                    next();
                }
        
    });
```

I need to do this, because I need to utilize LUIS and it does not support language with which my users can communicate with the bot (Slovak). However, bot is multilingual, that means I am supporting also English. In case my user uses English language (he or she set it up and this preference is stored within session.preferredLocale) I am doing translation that is not needed.

How can I access session in receive middleware, so I can check whether there is need to do the translation or not? And also, how can I sendTyping before doing the translation? It can sometime take longer time, and so bot becomes unresponsive.

Please note, that I cannot use event.textLocale, as I am planning to publish bot to messenger, and it does not post this information. I also do not want to use Locale recognizer API as another cognitive service.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _"I also do not want to use Locale recognizer API as another cognitive service"_ but there's another endpoint that tells you the language the text is in: `http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Detect?text`

Comment: this is what I meant by locale recognizer. (translator is part of Azure's cognitive services offering, including detrect aka locale recognizer), another call which will increase operational costs for the solution. I simply want to use preferred locale set within the session

Comment: @stuartd please do you know about the way, how to solve translation using session.preferredLocale

Comment: I'm not seeing any way to do that [in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512421.aspx) but one trick I have used in the past is to check how many words have changed in the translation process and use that as an indicator - so _"Ahoj svet"_  => _"Hello world"_ would count as translated because both words changed..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [`UniversalBot.loadSession()`](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.universalbot.html#loadsession)?

Syntax would be something like:

```
bot.use({
  recognize: function(event, next) {
    bot.loadSession(event.address, function (err, session) {
      // Do stuff, e.g API calls, session.sendTyping();
      var locale = resultOfApiCall.locale; // Or something else
      session.preferredLocale(locale).save().sendTyping();

      switch (locale) {
        case 'en-US':
          // More stuff, keep LuisRecognizer enabled
          break;
      }
      next(); 
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I was not aware of existing of this loadSession event. This is exactly what I was looking for and solves my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I ran into a problem using your solution. I am getting following error: ERROR: ChatConnector: startConversation - address is invalid.
Error: Invalid address.  Please have you tested whether it works?

Answer (score 1):

After digging in documentation I found this piece of middleware: **botbuilder** - from documentation botbuilder gets called in series once an incoming message has been bound to a session. Executed after receive middleware.  Solution than looks like this:

```
bot.use({    
    botbuilder: function(session,next)
    {
           if(session.preferredLocale != 'en')
              //DO Translation Here
    }
});
```